# C++ Function returning a linked list

Tags: c++, templates, input, linked-list

What I have been asked to do:
Q) A sentence consists of a list of characters terminated by a full stop. Write a function which returns a linked list of characters, where the characters are typed in by the user and added to the list. The returned list should include the full stop.
It should be called as:

```
LinkedList<char> *sentence;
sentence = setUpSentence();
```

I have attempted to write pieces of this but I'm struggling as this is my first time working with linked lists & functions like this.

Main File

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
    #include "ListNode.h"
    #include "Node.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    LinkedList<char> *setUpSentence() {
        //allocate the linked list objet
        LinkedList<char> *sentence = new LinkedList<char>();
        char ch;
        do {
            cout << "Enter characters to add, enter full stop to finish adding." << endl;
            ch = cin.get();
            sentence->addAtEnd(ch);
        } while (ch != '.');

        return sentence;
    }

    int main() {

        //call the function, store the returned pointer in sentence variable
        LinkedList<char> *sentence = setUpSentence();
        //working with the linked list
        sentence = setUpSentence();



        cout << sentence->getAtFront() << endl;

//delete to avoid memory leak
        delete sentence;
    }
```

The error I am getting when attempting to run this attempt at beginning to write this function is :

> after entering 1 character into the console and pressing enter, the loop continues and outputs "enter characters to add...." but this appears twice each time after entering a character?

Any ideas?

Code from functions from the LinkedList.h file that are used in my main:

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addAtEnd(T item)
{
    if (size == 0)
        addAtFront(item);
    else
    {
        // ListNode<T>* temp = findAt(size - 1);
        ListNode<T> *l = new ListNode<T>(item, last, nullptr);
        last->next = l;
        last = l;
        size++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getAtFront()
{
    if (size > 0)
    {
        current = first;
        return first->item;
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

edit:
addAtFront Method from LinkedList.h file

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addAtFront(T item)
{
    ListNode<T> *l = new ListNode<T>(item, NULL, first);
    first = l;
    if (last == NULL)
        last = l;
    size = 1;
}
```

Comment: That recursive call should obviously be questionable, especially considering the result is completely unused. Secondly, you didn't provide *all* the relevant code, leaving us to have to *guess* that `addAtFront` is implemented correctly.

Comment: @whozCraig my code updated with alex Petrenko's suggestions & addAtFront method included.

Comment: You can't delete `sentence` then use `cout` later on `sentence`.

Comment: Is there any problem with the code now? I don't think the original error applies any more for the changed code.

Comment: You should not be calling `setUpSentence()` 2 times. The first time will leak memory.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks. error updated in the question now. The output is repeated every time i enter a character? e.g if i enter k and press enter, the output message at the start of the do while loop executes twice?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're trying to make a recursive call to `setUpSentence()` in the return statement, this does not make sense. I think it should look like this instead:

```
LinkedList<char> * setUpSentence() {
    // make sure to allocate the linked list object
    LinkedList<char> *sentence = new LinkedList<char>();
    char ch;
    do {
        cout << "Enter characters to add, enter full stop to finish adding." << endl;
        ch = cin.get();
        sentence->addAtEnd(ch);
    } while (ch != '.');

    return sentence;
}

int main() {
    // calling the function, store the returned pointer in sentence variable
    LinkedList *sentence = setUpSentence();

    // ... working with the linked list ...

    delete sentence;  // don't forget to delete it to avoid memory leak!
}
```